# Are Keychain Passwords Stored in iCloud by Default?

Tags: macos, icloud, password, keychain, monterey

Are Keychain passwords stored in iCloud by default?

If so is there a way to disable iCloud Keychain without having to sign-in to iCloud.

I have NOT signed into iCloud on the Mac I am using.

Was going to sign-in into iCloud on the Mac to see if Keychains was disabled but chose not to because I was asked to provide my Mac user account password and my iPhone passcode to proceed.  Something I did not feel comfortable doing.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you might be on osX Monterey (as tag'ed). Keychain passwords are stored in iCloud by default. When you turn on iCloud Keychain, your passwords, passkeys, and credit card information are automatically stored in iCloud and kept up to date across all your Apple devices. However, based on the general approach in previous macOS versions, you should be able to manage iCloud Keychain settings in the "Apple ID" or "iCloud" section of your System Preferences. Btw, I've seen somewhere mentioned *disable iCloud Keychain without signing in to iCloud* by *Terminal* (haven't tried though).

Comment: From your following response it is unclear to me if my passwords are sucked into iCloud or not.  You said: "Keychain passwords are stored in iCloud by default. When you turn on iCloud Keychain, your passwords, passkeys, and credit card information are automatically stored in iCloud"   I have NOT turned on iCloud Keychain.  I have NOT signed into iCloud from the Mac.  Please clarify.

Comment: let me rephrase, I don't think keychain passwords are stored in iCloud unless you have specifically turned on iCloud Keychain. You can check from Keychain Access app within Utilities; In the sidebar, you will see a list of keychains. The keychains that are stored locally on your Mac will have the label "Local" next to them.

Comment: TROUBLING. Using the MacOS Keychain Access app I noticed that Keychain record for my email password displayed WHERE: iCloud and not WHERE: Local.  However in the LEFT SIDE Keychain column there is LOGIN Keychain and LOCAL ITEMS Keychain there is no iCLOUD Keychain.  I do not want to signin to iCloud on the Mac as it requires me to provide Apple with my Mac User Account Password and my iPhone Access Code.  It is unfortunate that Apple does not make it clear to what is actually taking place.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204085 - see "If you turn off iCloud Keychain" may explain... hope it helps